# How to automatically copy the data in one column, to a new column in a different sheet, each day?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to copy all the data from one Spreadsheet.  Most of it is all in one column, another individual cell (not in that column) would need to be copied as well.

All of this data would need to get copied, once a day, into a new spreadsheet, adding into the next column from the day before.  The data from the individual cell would go into row A, and the data from the column of copied data would start at row B and go down from there.

I'm definitely out of my element with Scripts, and the script I was able to piece together from others' questions doesn't take into account 1) that the original data is not on the first tab of the spreadsheet, and I'm unsure of how to adjust that or 2) that there is that individual cell of data that also needs to get copied.  Here is what I am using so far:

```
function copyColumnB() {
var sourceSpreadsheetId = '____';
var destinationSpreadsheetId = '_____';

var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId).getActiveSheet();
var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId).getActiveSheet();
var lastColumn = destinationSheet.getLastColumn();
var nextColumn = lastColumn + 1;

// Insert a new column before Column B
destinationSheet.insertColumns(2);

// Get the updated lastColumn and nextColumn values
lastColumn = destinationSheet.getLastColumn();
nextColumn = lastColumn + 1;

// Copy the values from sourceValues to the newly inserted column
destinationSheet.getRange(1, nextColumn, sourceValues.length, 1).setValues(sourceValues);

// Delete the extra column that was inserted after copying
destinationSheet.deleteColumn(nextColumn + 1);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remapping the columns:

```
function remapcolumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [hs,...vs1] = sh1.getDataRange().getValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e],i) => [b,a,c,e,d] );//put the column letters wherever you wish
  sh2.getRange(2,1,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1)
}

function aToB() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [hs,...vs1] = sh1.getDataRange().getValues().map(([a,,,,],i) => [a] );//put the column letters wherever you wish
  sh2.getRange(2,2,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1)
}
```